# jquery first time page loading issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I first time load my website then images are jumping on each other 
but when I refresh them it will look normal as I need it .

To see first time output  of mixed images jumping on each other use
ctrl+shift+r

Jquery is creating problem when I load the website first time?
Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a jQuery issue. This is a network download issue. By hard refreshing (ctrl+shift+r), you are forcing the browser to re-download CSS assets, which increases the amount of time before it can properly style the page.

There is a front end design tactic that might suit you well in this scenario.

You have two sections that are "above-the-fold" when you first load the page. Instead of downloading an external stylesheet before rendering and painting these two sections, you can extract the "critical" CSS to a  block in your HTML.

This ensures your CSS is there without wasting time with another HTTP request. For more information on what critical CSS is, I'd recommend this article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/08/understanding-critical-css/#what-is-critical-css